# NullPointerException when concurrent requests are sent to Drools

Tags: java, concurrency, nullpointerexception, drools

In our application we have an interceptor to invoke drools rules for each request we received. After adding new set of rules (in separate DRL files) when multiple requests are sent we get NPE (see below stack trace). Unfortunately I don't know in which rule and where this occurs as the stack trace doesn't give me much information:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.drools.core.reteoo.BaseLeftTuple.get(BaseLeftTuple.java:500)
at org.drools.core.reteoo.QueryElementNode$UnificationNodeViewChangedEventListener.rowAdded(QueryElementNode.java:331)
at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakQueryTerminalNode.doLeftInserts(PhreakQueryTerminalNode.java:65)
at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakQueryTerminalNode.doNode(PhreakQueryTerminalNode.java:37)
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.innerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:311)
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalStackEntry(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:224)
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.outerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:166)
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evaluateNetwork(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:116)
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.reEvaluateNetwork(RuleExecutor.java:200)
at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:67)
at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireNextItem(DefaultAgenda.java:937)
at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:1201)
at org.drools.core.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:958)
at org.drools.core.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.fireAllRules(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:932)
at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:256)
at org.drools.core.command.runtime.rule.FireAllRulesCommand.execute(FireAllRulesCommand.java:106)
at org.drools.core.command.runtime.rule.FireAllRulesCommand.execute(FireAllRulesCommand.java:32)
at org.drools.core.command.runtime.BatchExecutionCommandImpl.execute(BatchExecutionCommandImpl.java:155)
at org.drools.core.command.runtime.BatchExecutionCommandImpl.execute(BatchExecutionCommandImpl.java:76)
at org.drools.core.impl.StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.execute(StatelessKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:358)
at com.comp.test.validation.impl.cmprules.cmpRulesBridgeImpl.validate(cmpRulesBridgeImpl.java:154)
at com.comp.test.au.validation.impl.cmprules.CreateInvestorAccountRulesValidator.doValidation(CreateInvestorAccountRulesValidator.java:366)
at com.comp.test.validation.impl.BaseJAXBElementValidator.validate(BaseJAXBElementValidator.java:78)
at org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(ValidationUtils.java:83)
at org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(ValidationUtils.java:55)
at com.comp.test.ws.interceptor.RequestUnmarshallingFaultValidatingEndpointInterceptor.onRequestUnmarshalled(RequestUnmarshallingFaultValidatingEndpointInterceptor.java:85)
at com.comp.test.ws.interceptor.RequestUnmarshallingEndpointInterceptor.handleRequest(RequestUnmarshallingEndpointInterceptor.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy260.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartEndpointInterceptor.handleRequest(DelegatingSmartEndpointInterceptor.java:78)
at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:224)
... 22 more
```

To give you more information, we Have 4 DRL files, one is called Prerequisite which contains rules that loads stuff we need as well as declared types and queries. There are also rules that may update declared types ... Are declared types thread safe? What about queries? Can you please help me on this?

Unfortunately I can't give more details as there are nearly 100 rules and I don't know which one causes this error.

Drools 6.0.0.Final

Updated:

@luane I put some logs and everything seems normal it's just that I'm not sure about this query:

'

```
query calculateTotalSumInsured(List riders, String benefit, BigDecimal totalRiderSum)
    ?listRiderBenefitsByType(riders, benefit;)
    totalRiderSum := BigDecimal() from accumulate (
            ic : Cover(!("I".equals(status)))
                        from riders,
            init(BigDecimal total = BigDecimal.ZERO;),
            action( total = (ic.getActualSumInsured() != null ? total.add(ic.getActualSumInsured()) : total);),
            result(total)
    )

end'
```

I'm not sure what the **?** before **listRiderBenefitsByType**() means... FYI: it's another query. Is it causing a problem in concurrent environment? 
From the Drools documentation it says:

> Drools now provides Prolog style derivation queries, as an experimental feature. What this means is that a query or the 'when' part of a rule may call a query, via a query element. This is also recursive so that a query may call itself. A query element may be prefixed with a question mark '?' which indicuates that we have a pattern construct that will pull data, rather than the normal reactive push nature of patterns. If the ? is ommitted the query will be executed as a live "open query" with reactiveness, similar to how normal patterns work.

But I don't understand what that means to be honest!

Comment: I see from the stack trace that this happens during rule execution, while calling `fireAllrules()`. You can attach an event listener to the session to log all events. This will show you during which rule execution the problem occurs. Also, it looks like a query row being added. - Presumably, this is code that's new in 6.0, so it might be a bug. Trying 6.1 might be an option.

Comment: Thanks... I will attach an event listener. As for the bug, is there any bug related to that query row already logged for v 6.0? if yes, can you please give me the link? Thanks

Comment: Can't say for sure - I'm not watching Drools development closely, and it would be difficult to tell from the stack trace alone anyway. You might try the Drools user list, a Google Groups thing now.

Comment: @laune Can you please tell me which listener and what method? We currently have DefaultAgendaEventListener, not sure which one should of its method should I put logs

Comment: before/afterMatchFired and matchCreated are the ones.